# Sharing ArcGlobe bookmarks with ArcScene and vice versa?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, bookmarks, arcglobe

I am working on a flyover animation and would like to be able to seamlessly go between ArcGlobe and ArcScene and the other way around. I tried saving and using the bookmarks in but this does not seem to work.

Is there another way to synchronize a specific location in ArcGlobe and ArcScene?

Answer (score 1):

**ArcGlobe** projects all data onto a globe-shaped surface using one particular coordinate system—**Cube Projection.** All data added to an empty ArcGlobe document is projected on the fly to this coordinate system. Data that does not have projection information associated with it cannot be added into ArcGlobe. Being spherical, this application is optimized for visualizing geography at a global scale.

**ArcScene** projects all data in an ArcScene document according to the first layer added to the document. Usually a planar projection, ArcScene is geared for those with smaller spatial datasets who want to examine a defined study area.

If you can use Cube Projection in ArcScene it would work. But it is not supported.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q8000000sv000000